# Remove blank cells containing a formula in OpenOffice Calc

Tags: openoffice

I am attempting to remove blank cell values which also have a formula, from a column in OpenOffice calc.

**Row numbers and corresponding data:**

```
1  A1
2  A4
3  
4  A9
5  
6  A98
```

Each cell in the data column has a formula, so technically they are not blank, but no data shows in the sheet for certain rows.

*fwiw, the formula finds unique values of two other columns and copies these to a third column:* 
 `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$100,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(1/(ISNA(MATCH($A$1:$A$100,$B$1:$B$100,0))*ROW($A$1:$A$100)*($A$1:$A$100<>""))),ROWS($1:3))),"")`

Here's my [example sheet](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Cwq1iaWWUfN0iR4-2-KMDzrjgKsPGnJh).

So far I've tried adding a Standard Filter by selecting the data column then going to `Standard Filter`, choosing the data column, setting condition to `=`, value to `Not Empty`, then selecting the `Copy to` option and pointing to a cell in an empty column in the sheet.   Obviously this doesn't work since my cells have a formula in them.

Is there a similarly easy method to do the same thing with cells containing a formula, but where no data exists in the sheet for the same cell?

Comment: Use *Data -> Filter -> AutoFilter* as explained at https://askubuntu.com/questions/943662/libreoffice-calc-delete-empty-rows.

Comment: Tried this ([same example sheet with autofilter](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19UWtbTJO0T8fYrpsf1_eYa36hW-ya7Fg/view?usp=sharing)).  After applying autofilter, I clicked the drop down over Col C and then clicked Empty.   Every cell in the sheet disappeared.

Comment: Yes, that's what's supposed to happen.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After turning on AutoFilter, follow step 3 from https://askubuntu.com/questions/943662/libreoffice-calc-delete-empty-rows, which it sounds like you did.

[image: step 3 - filter for empty]

Now, only the empty rows are shown.  Notice the visible rows are 3 and 5. 
 Select and then delete the rows, for example by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>.

[image: step 4]

Step 5 is to reset the filter.  To do this, I selected column C and went to *Data -> Filter -> AutoFilter*.  When I tried it just now, for some reason I had to do it twice before it worked.  Notice the rows are back to normal: 1, 2, 3, 4.

The result:

[image: 3 non-empty rows]